# How to add new item in Links list using Managed Client Object Model?

Tags: list, client-object-model, list-item

I have created a standard SharePoint Links list, using Managed Client Object Model (for Silverlight). Here's the code:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sitePath);
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);

ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation();
lci.Title = "My Links";
lci.Description = string.Empty;
lci.TemplateType = ListTemplateType.Links;
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(lci);
clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

I want to be able to add items to this list programmatically, but I am stuck. Normally, I'd add a new list item in the following manner:

```
ListItemCreationInformation lici = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem item = list.AddItem(lici);
item.ParseAndSetFieldValue("Some field name", "Some field value");
item.ParseAndSetFieldValue("Some other field name", "Some other field value"); 
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

The problem is that I don't know which field I should target for the link's URL and Title fields. Help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way. There is a class `FieldUrlValue` in the Client Ojbect Model for this type of situations. Here's how I implemented it:

```
ListItemCreationInformation lici = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem item = list.AddItem(lici);

FieldUrlValue link = new FieldUrlValue();
link.Url = "http://some-address";
link.Description = "Some Address Title";
item["URL"] = link; 

item.["Some other field name"] = "Some other field value";  
item.Update(); 
clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

I hope the others will benefit from my find. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the settings page of the Links list you will see the names of the field you are after - **URL**

There is no separate address and tile filed - just enter it as HTML.

```
<a href="http://someaddress">Some Title</a>
```

Comment: Ryan, thank you for helping me out. If I use the line you have suggested, I get the following exception message:
`[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException] = {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Invalid URL: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.Sha...`

Do you know perhaps what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I've solved the problem and posted the solution.